Excel Interop error on opening .xlsx file Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))
I have C# batch process Opening, Calculating and Closing many Excel workbooks. After a varying number of iterations, when I try to open the next workbook, I get the below error.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). 
When I try to Open the workbook in Excel UI, Excel hangs for many minutes, then eventually shows a very long list of auto recovered files. Once this list is cleared manually in the UI, the batch application no longer errors. But only until the the auto recovered files list grows too long again.
This occurs despite

WorkBooks being read-only files
Using ExcelWorkBook.EnableAutoRecover = false;

How to solve this programmatically ?

I searched far and wide for temp files to delete, but it seems Excel auto recovered files must be removed from the registry.
Run this PowerShell before each iteration when no workbooks are Open. Amend the version number to your use case.
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Resiliency" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

